# Usage of a/the for "untold number of"

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

In "Cambridge preparation to TOEFL"'93 book I've found the phrase:

*_ untold number of people perished while attempting to cross Death Valley.*

The correct answer is "an".
But I have that feeling that "the untold number" = "the specific number, i.e. 12345 that was not told". So the article should or could be "the".

If there is any difference, tell me the British version of this.

Comment: If the exact  number is not given but instead such  a vague phrase as "untold"  is used, *an* is the correct determiner. You go with what is stated. If they had stated the exact number, then yes *the 12345 people perished...* would be correct.

Comment: This is like *an unspecified number of people...* It doesn't matter if the number *could be* specified. What matters is that it isn't, and you choose your determiner based on what is actually given, not what it might stand for.

Comment: The problem here is that not some vague "untold number" was not told, but the specific precise number that was not told.

Comment: If the speaker knows that the actual number of people is 12345, he could theoretically say *the untold number* or *the unspecified number* if for some reason he wanted to keep the exact number secret, as in playing Dungeons & Dragons: *you meet an untold number of dragons*, *the untold number of dragons follows you into the next cave*. But this is not exactly everyday usage, where *an untold number* is used because it's not important or not  possible to specify  the untold number.

Comment: Or  even if the speaker doesn't know the exact number, he can say *the untold number of people/dragons*, but it's rather unusual.  And it would be  subject to the same norm that upon first mention,  *an untold number* would almost always be used. Contra wise, even if the speaker knows that the exact number is 12345, he doesn't have to say *the untold number*. It's up to the speaker as to whether he wants to make a definite or indefinite reference. The idiomatic way is to say *an untold number* **because** no one knows the exact number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *untold number* is not, as you think, a number which has not been reported. *Tell* in this phrase retains its old meaning of *count*, and *untold* means, literally, *countless*. An untold number is therefore an undetermined number, one which is by definition indefinite.

(And if this meaning of *tell* seems unlikely, consider German *Zahl*, "number" and *erzählen*, "narrate"; the related words *toll*, as in *death toll*, and *tale*, as in *the tale of years*; and the same transfer of meaning in the Romance-rooted *count*, as in *recount* an experience and your *account* of events.)

Comment: Thanks, StoneyB. Alan Carmack's explanation is nice as well. While yours seems much deeper.

Comment: The Online Etymology Dictionary gives some origins as well. Apparently an old meaning of "tell" in English is "count."

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=untold

Comment: @KatherineLockwood I think I said this in my second sentence . . .